# Redistribute files into multiple sub-directories with maximum size

Tags: bash, bin-packing

I have a large directory `files_pdf` which contains 110 000 pdf-documents. Each of these documents has different file-size.

I would like to redistribute all of these documents in a set of sub-directories such that all sub-directories have *about* the same total accumulated size. I do not want to split files into multiple parts.

I have tried:

```
split -b 4000k myfile segment
```

But it will break my PDF in some cases.

Comment: You will probably want to iterate over the files while maintaining a current directory toward which you're going to copy them, which you will change once the limit is reached. How do you want to handle that directory size? Should a file that will raise the directory size over that "equal size" be the last file copied to the directory, or should it be copied to the next directory?

Comment: What you are trying to solve is far from easy. This is called the [bin-packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: How many subdirectories do you want to split the directory into?  (Is it a fixed number, or do the directories need to have a maximum size or a maximum number of files, or ...?)

Comment: This very much depends on the distribution of the file sizes. If it's somehow normal, you'd be okay with just random assignment to any of the dirs (think `md5sum`). If the distribution has some really huge files, you'll need to solve the 'assignment problem' somehow yourself based on how hard are your constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution based on the bin-packing First-fit algorithm might be the following.

Create a file called `bin_packing.awk`:

```
function first_fit(v, file) {
    # find first bin that can accomodate the volume
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
        if (b[i] > v) {
            b[i] -= v
            bc[i]++
            cmd="mv "file" subdir_" i
            print cmd
            # system(cmd)
            return
        }
    }
    # no bin found, create new bin
    if (i > n) {
        b[++n] = c - v
        bc[n]++
        cmd="mkdir subdir_"n
        print cmd
        # system(cmd)
        cmd="mv "file" subdir_"n
        print cmd
        # system(cmd)
    }
    return
}
BEGIN{ if( (c+0) == 0) exit }
{ first_fit($1,$2) }
END { print "REPORT:"
    print "Created",n,"directories"
    for(i=1;i<=n;++i) print "- subdir_"i,":", c-b[i],"bytes",bc[i],"files"
}
```

And then execute the line:

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*pdf' -printf "%s %p\n"
```

This will create a list of files with the file size in bytes in front of it. Something similar to:

```
8 file_1
1 file_2
8 file_3
4 file_4
4 file_5
4 file_6
10 file_7
...
```

Now you can run the following:

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*pdf' -printf "%s %p\n" \
  | awk -v c=100000 -f bin_packing.awk
```

In the above line, you set the value `c` to be the maximum size a directory can have in bytes. The above value `c=100000` is only an example.

This will create output like:

```
...
mv file_47 subdir_6
mv file_48 subdir_6
mv file_49 subdir_5
mv file_50 subdir_6
REPORT:
Created 6 directories
- subdir_1 : 49 bytes 12 files
- subdir_2 : 49 bytes 9 files
- subdir_3 : 49 bytes 8 files
- subdir_4 : 49 bytes 8 files
- subdir_5 : 48 bytes 8 files
- subdir_6 : 37 bytes 5 files
```

If you like what you see, you might consider removing the comments in the `bin_packing.awk` script.

**note:** this clearly assumed that your filenames are normal. I.e. no funny characters and no spaces in them.

Comment: its worked fine, but there's a problem i have tried it on 534 .pdf file and it created a directory for each pdf file as below : - subdir_525 : 217092 bytes 1 files
- subdir_526 : 263051 bytes 1 files
- subdir_527 : 205648 bytes 1 files
- subdir_528 : 341967 bytes 1 files
- subdir_529 : 177217 bytes 1 files
- subdir_530 : 205638 bytes 1 files
- subdir_531 : 217096 bytes 1 files
- subdir_532 : 176677 bytes 1 files
- subdir_533 : 207963 bytes 1 files
- subdir_534 : 176119 bytes 1 files

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh You have to set the size of the directory correct. If it is too small you have one dir per file. It is the value `c`